How to get all the working sets? Revit API C#
I want to display all the Worksets in a combobox. I looked at the revitapidocs website, there is a GetWorksetIds() method there. But for some reason it doesn't work in my code.
WorksetTable worksetTable = _doc.GetWorksetTable();

newChangeWorkSetComboBox.Items.Clear();

IList<WorksetId> worksetIds = worksetTable.GetWorksetIds(); 
foreach (WorksetId worksetId in worksetIds)
{
    Workset workset = worksetTable.GetWorkset(worksetId);
    if (workset != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(workset.Name))
    {
        newChangeWorkSetComboBox.Items.Add(workset.Name);
    }
}

StackPanel_ChangeWorkSets.Children.Add(newChangeWorkSetComboBox);


The following error appears:

Error (active) CS1061 "WorksetTable" does not contain the definition of "GetWorksetIds", and an available extension method "GetWorksetIds" could not be found that accepts the type "WorksetTable" as the first argument (perhaps the using directive or assembly reference was omitted).

How can this method be replaced in the revit 2023?

Turns out that there is a FilteredWorksetCollector that does an excellent job with this task.
var worksets = new FilteredWorksetCollector(_doc)
        .OfKind(WorksetKind.UserWorkset)
        .ToWorksets();

newChangeWorkSetComboBox.Items.Clear();

foreach (Workset workset in worksets)
{
    newChangeWorkSetComboBox.Items.Add(workset.Name);
}
StackPanel_ChangeWorkSets.Children.Add(newChangeWorkSetComboBox);


You can try this:
ICollection<Workset> GetWorksetsCollection= GetWorksetsCollection(doc);
if (GetWorksetsCollection != null)
{
  //Do your stuff here. For each workset.Name add a new ChangeWorkSetComboBox Item.
}

public static ICollection<Workset> GetWorksetsCollection(Document doc)
        {
            try
            {
                // Enumerating worksets in a document and getting basic information for each
                FilteredWorksetCollector collector = new FilteredWorksetCollector(doc);

                // find all user worksets
                collector.OfKind(WorksetKind.UserWorkset);
                IList<Workset> worksets = collector.ToWorksets();

                if (worksets != null)
                {
                    return worksets;
                }
                else { return null; }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorLogger.LogError("WorksetsFunctions", "GetWorksetsCollection", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

Retrieves an ICollection of Workset class that you can work with like a list, with each one of their properties: Id, IsDefaultWorkset, IsEditable, IsOpen, IsVisibleByDefault, Kind, Name, Owner, UniqueId.
